# How do I remove verified domain in App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

As the title says, is there a way to remove the verified domain from https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bitV.png

Thanks.

I need to verify just a subdomain here, but accidentally verified main domain. Now, within Google Search Console, any subdomain I try adding is automatically verified, but won't verify in app engine, so I'm trying to start it all over.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible 'on demand'.

I think the best you can do is to remove the mapping (TXT, etc) that you added to your DNS configuration settings and then the next time Google tries to reverify your domain (they do this on a regular basis which is why you're told not to delete the entries after the initial verification), it won't find the mappings and so marks the domain as unverified.

If you're having problems verifying a sub-domain in GAE, you should post that as a question with what you've done and what you're seeing (error, what happens/doesn't happen).